# How to access a typedefed object outside its translation unit

Tags: c

**test.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_H_INCLUDED
#define TEST_H_INCLUDED

int func(void);
typedef int (*FPTR)(void);

#endif // TEST_H_INCLUDED
```

**func.c**

```
#include "test.h"

static int x = 22; // persistent with external linkage.

int func(void)
{
  extern int x; // Referencing declaration
  static int count = 0; // persistent within block
  printf("%d : %d\n",++count,++x);
return 1;
}

FPTR funcptr = func; // persistent with external linkage. ??
```

**main.c**

```
#include "test.h"

#include <stdio.h>

extern funcptr; // referencing declaration ??

int main(void)
{
func();
funcptr(); // Compile Time Error Here
return 0;
}
```

This fails with error `called object ‘funcptr’ is not a function or function pointer`.

Am I breaking any cardinal rules here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong syntax; should be

```
 extern FPTR funcptr;
```

because an `extern` [declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/declarations) still needs to mention a type.

And you'll better call it with `(*funcptr)()` which is at least more readable.

Comment: oops ! that was easy.. Sorry for the trouble folks and thanks for the time. Taking your second suggestion too.